# Adding Contact programmatically in Android

Tags: android, contacts

After a lot of search I found that how we add contact programmatically in Android. but I have a small issue in adding contact. Code which I am using:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> op_list = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>(); 
    op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI) 
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "Phone") 
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "null") 
        //.withValue(RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE, RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DEFAULT) 
        .build()); 

 // first and last names 
      op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI) 
  .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0) 
        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE) 
        .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, name) 
        .withValue(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, name) 
        .build()); 

      op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI) 
              .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0) 
              .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
              .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, mobileNo)
              .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE )
              .build());
      op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI) 
              .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)

      .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
      .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, emailAddr)
      .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME)
      .build());

 try{ 
  ContentProviderResult[] results = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, op_list); 
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contact Added Sucessfully..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }catch(Exception e){ 
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Problem in Adding Contact ..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  e.printStackTrace(); 
 }
```

when my code is running I got following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify both or neither of ACCOUNT_NAME and ACCOUNT_TYPE; URI: content://com.android.contacts/raw_contacts,
```

What I specify in this Account type and account name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works for me

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

    Log.i("Line38", "Here");
       ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)  
                    .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE)          
                    .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME)          
                    .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)      
                    .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)      
                    .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)      
                    .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "u232786seee")
                    .withValue(StructuredName.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP,true)
                    .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,"23232343434")
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, "4343")
    .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, "")
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, "")
    .build());

    //Log.i("Line43", Data.CONTENT_URI.toString()+" - "+rawContactInsertIndex);

    try {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @GauravKumawat   `ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)  
                    .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE)          
                    .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME)          
                    .build());`
You are adding this Contact to acount of type "accountType" ( AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME) I don't think is a good solution. It's better to use `null`

Comment: @Goldie What are you trying to say?